# Density plots with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, kernel-density

I am trying to produce something similar to `densityplot()` from the `lattice package`, using `ggplot2` after using multiple imputation with the `mice` package. Here is a reproducible example:

```
require(mice)
dt <- nhanes
impute <- mice(dt, seed = 23109)
x11()
densityplot(impute)
```

Which produces:

[image: densityplot output that I want to improve in ggplot]

I would like to have some more control over the output (and I am also using this as a learning exercise for ggplot). So, for the `bmi` variable, I tried this:

```
bar <- NULL
for (i in 1:impute$m) {
    foo <- complete(impute,i)
    foo$imp <- rep(i,nrow(foo))
    foo$col <- rep("#000000",nrow(foo))
    bar <- rbind(bar,foo)
}

imp <-rep(0,nrow(impute$data))
col <- rep("#D55E00", nrow(impute$data))
bar <- rbind(bar,cbind(impute$data,imp,col))
bar$imp <- as.factor(bar$imp)

x11()
ggplot(bar, aes(x=bmi, group=imp, colour=col)) + geom_density()
+ scale_fill_manual(labels=c("Observed", "Imputed"))
```

which produces this:
[image]

So there are several problems with it:

1. The colours are wrong. It seems my attempt to control the colours is completely wrong/ignored
2. There are unwanted horizontal and vertical lines
3. I would like the legend to show Imputed and Observed but my code gives the error `invalid argument to unary operator`

Moreover, it seems like quite a lot of work to do what is accomplished in one line with `densityplot(impute)` - so I wondered if I might be going about this in the wrong way entirely ?

**Edit**: I should add the fourth  problem, as noted by @ROLO:

.4. The range of the plots seems to be incorrect.

Comment: See also this post on the topic of comparing densities in r across groups: http://eeyore.ucdavis.edu/stat141/MultipleDensityPlots.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it is more complicated using ggplot2 is that you are using `densityplot` from the mice package (`mice::densityplot.mids` to be precise - check out its code), not from lattice itself. This function has all the functionality for plotting `mids` result classes from `mice` built in. If you would try the same using `lattice::densityplot`, you would find it to be at least as much work as using ggplot2.

But without further ado, here is how to do it with ggplot2:

```
require(reshape2)
# Obtain the imputed data, together with the original data
imp <- complete(impute,"long", include=TRUE)
# Melt into long format
imp <- melt(imp, c(".imp",".id","age"))
# Add a variable for the plot legend
imp$Imputed<-ifelse(imp$".imp"==0,"Observed","Imputed")

# Plot. Be sure to use stat_density instead of geom_density in order
#  to prevent what you call "unwanted horizontal and vertical lines"
ggplot(imp, aes(x=value, group=.imp, colour=Imputed)) + 
    stat_density(geom = "path",position = "identity") +
    facet_wrap(~variable, ncol=2, scales="free")
```

[image]

But as you can see the ranges of these plots are smaller than those from `densityplot`. This behaviour should be controlled by parameter `trim` of `stat_density`, but this seems not to work. After fixing the code of `stat_density` I got the following plot:

[image]

Still not exactly the same as the `densityplot` original, but much closer.

Edit: for a true fix we'll need to wait for the next major version of ggplot2, see [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/652).

Comment: Great. Thank you (+1). May I ask how did you fix the code to extend the range ?

Comment: Sure. See [here](http://pastebin.com/cr329eru). Just a quick hack. I'm still figuring out package development, and when that works out and I have time I'll look for a better solution and submit it to the `ggplot2` devs.

Comment: Thanks again. That works great. I'm sorry to ask another question, but I am a beginner with R - I understand the changes you made to the code, however can you tell me how do you find the code that you had to change ?

Comment: I looked it up on [github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/stat-density.r).

Answer (score 5):

You can ask Hadley to add a fortify method for this mids class. E.g.

```
fortify.mids <- function(x){
 imps <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(x$m), function(i){
   data.frame(complete(x, i), Imputation = i, Imputed = "Imputed")
 }))
 orig <- cbind(x$data, Imputation = NA, Imputed = "Observed")
 rbind(imps, orig)
}
```

ggplot 'fortifies' non-data.frame objects prior to plotting

```
ggplot(fortify.mids(impute), aes(x = bmi, colour = Imputed, 
   group = Imputation)) +
geom_density() + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c(Imputed = "#000000", Observed = "#D55E00"))
```

note that each ends with a '+'. Otherwise the command is expected to be complete. This is why the legend did not change. And the line starting with a '+' resulted in the error.

[image]

You can melt the result of fortify.mids to plot all variables in one graph

```
library(reshape)
Molten <- melt(fortify.mids(impute), id.vars = c("Imputation", "Imputed"))
ggplot(Molten, aes(x = value, colour = Imputed, group = Imputation)) + 
geom_density() + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c(Imputed = "#000000", Observed = "#D55E00")) +
facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice. Thank you, (+1). May I ask, is it possible to prevent the horizontal and vertical lines from plotting ?:

Comment: geom_density() creates polygons, not lines. Hence the vertical and horzontal lines. Polygons have the benefit that you can use a colour for the outline and a fill colour. See http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/stat_density.html