# Error in density.default.....need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically

Tags: r

I am using the `mice` package to obtain completed data. 
I believe the problem is that I am not doing imputations for all the data, and so some of them have NAs.  (some variables with missing data are used simply to predict missingness in others so I don't want to impute those.

I can duplicate the problem with this code:

```
require(mice)
impute <- mice(
    nhanes, 
    imputationMethod = c(
        "",        # age
        "pmm",     # bmi
        "pmm",  # hyp
        ""         # chl
    ),
    seed = 101)
x11()
densityplot(impute)

Error in density.default(x = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_,  : 
  need at least 2 points to select a bandwidth automatically
```

How can I get the densityplots ? If I replace the `""` with `"pmm"` for `chl` or just run `impute <- mice(nhanes)` then it will work with this example, to produce this:
[image]

but I can't do that with my own data, so I'm looking for another way....just to get the 
density plots for `bmi` and `hyp`, after running `mice` with my code above which does not impute values for `chl`

**Edit:**
I know I can use the methods in the answer to my [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12056989/density-plots-with-multiple-groups) question using `ggplot`, but in this case I really need to work with `densityplot`

Comment: I get an error with the impute call: "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1" and a warning. Using mice 2.13 with R 2.15.1

Comment: @DWin Sorry ! it was the wrong imputation method for hyp
. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will still have a large number of missing data in the 'chl'-column. You could use the `pkg:mice` function `complete` to pull together the original non-missing and the imputed values. But the `densityplot.mids` function will do it if you reverse the roles of data and formula as (eventually) described in the Details of the help page.

```
densityplot( x=impute , data= ~ bmi+hyp)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - but I think I didn't make myself clear in the question. I don't want a density plot for chl. I just want the plots for the ones that I am imputing: bmi and hyp in this example. So, in other words I want just the first 2 plots that are obtained from `impute <- mice(nhanes)` and then `densityplot(impute)`

Comment: Just take out the 'age' and 'chl' in the formula and they will not get processed.

Comment: Thanks again - I have updated the question to hopefully show what I am hoping to obtain.

Comment: OK. changing the call. Should be as hoped.